# MongoDB & Showdown. Save markdown as string

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, markdown, showdown

I've tried researching this and have not found and answer.

What im trying to do is saving markdown in mongodb as a string without parsing it. just saving it as a string..

Then fetch the markdown string from mongodb and use Showdown in react to parse it. However i cant get it to work.

Showdown seem to parse like the first markdown style for example 
`# Dillinger  [![N|Solid](https://cldup.com/dTxpPi9lDf.thumb.png)](https://nodesource.com/products/nsolid)`

Would become 
`<h1>dillingernsolidhttpscldupcomdtxppi9ldfthumbpng</h1>`

Kinda gotten stuck now.

Have someone made something similar and gotten it to work?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm showdown's current maintainer.

---

In [showdown's demo page](http://demo.showdownjs.com/#/%23%20Dillinger%20%20%5B!%5BN%7CSolid%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fcldup.com%2FdTxpPi9lDf.thumb.png)%5D(https%3A%2F%2Fnodesource.com%2Fproducts%2Fnsolid)) your example is working properly.

So, it seems the issue might be in storing/retrieving the text from the database.